# Why does my javascript not do anything when i added my if?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So everything works, but when I try adding the IF statement nothing works. Does anyone have an idea why the if statement in my javascript breaks everything?

MY INTENTION: 
    Have every element added the transition and padding;
    Change the background color of elements that contain children;
So

```
 nav
  ul
   li 1
   li 2
   li 3
   li 4
    ul
      li 4.1
      li 4.2
      li 4.3
   /ul
  li 5
 /ul
 /nav
```

means I would have the background of list item 4 to be changed to a color

```
    var x = document.getElementById('mainNav').getElementsByTagName("LI");
    var delay = 0;
    var transition = 0;
        for (i=0; i<=x.length; i++){

            x[i].style.padding = "0 0 0px 20px";
            x[i].style.transition = transition + "s " + delay +"s";
            delay += 0.02;
            transition += 0.07; // The higher the number, the slower of exponential decay
            if (x[i].getElementsByTagName('UL').getElementsByTagName('LI')>0){
                x[i].style.background = "red";
                }

        }
```

Comment: I can't understand your question.

Comment: Why don't you inspect the variables in your if statement and determine why it's not resulting in true?

Comment: And also why didn't you make a fiddle

Comment: I think that comparing a DOM element to 0 will always result in false. What do you expect that to do? Count the number of those elements for you? If so use `...('LI').length > 0`

Comment: I'm not good at vanilla js, but don't you need to add `.length` after `.getElementsByTagName('LI')` in the if statement? Just as you did in the for loop.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan I inspected, but the padding stays where it was before the javascript, which is 0 0 0 120%, and not 0 0 0 20px. However if i remove the if statement, it works flawlessly.

Comment: @ZachL i tried .length it doesnt do anything

Comment: The real problem here is that you have a huge gap in debugging skills. You need to inspect why `..getElementsByTagName('LI') >0 ` is not greater than 0. That my young grasshopper will lead you to the problem. P.s. How can you compare `[object] > 0`? You need `[object].length > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming what you're looking for is a nested `<ul>`, then this code has a couple issues:

```
         if (x[i].getElementsByTagName('UL').getElementsByTagName('LI')>0){
            x[i].style.background = "red";
         }
```

should be:

```
         if (x[i].querySelectorAll('ul li').length >0){
            x[i].style.background = "red";
         }
```

The first issue was that `getElementsByTagName()` returns a nodeList and you can't do `.getElementsByTagName('LI')` on a nodeList.  Then, even if you could do that, you can't just compare a nodeList to `> 0` as you have to look at the length.  I suggest combining the operations into one `querySelectorAll()` call and then using `.length`.

Comment: Genius! Worked like a charm! Quick question tho: will i be able to rerun similar code right after and change all x[i]'s transition properties or once I change it, it wont change?

Comment: @skarchmit - I'm not sure what you're asking.  You can change transition properties again in the future by rerunning this code.  I wouldn't recommend changing it in the middle of an animation, but other than that, it would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement has something incorrect:

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName('UL')
```

this will return a NodeList not just one DOM element. In case you only care about the first element you should do

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName('UL')[0]
```

then the other part:

```
.getElementsByTagName('LI')
```

also returns a NodeList. You need to call the **length** property to see how many elements are in the list:

```
.getElementsByTagName('LI').length > 0
```

so putting everything together:

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName('UL')[0].getElementsByTagName('LI').length > 0
```

But you should probably break that big IF condition into smaller statements and check for null.